# Novel about a man living in an empty shopping complex

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel, when I was a kid, that had a man that was hiding in an abandoned shopping complex, that appeared to be in a skyscraper. (It had multiple levels, at least). The guy was mortally afraid of someone or something that was chasing him and spent a lot of time getting guns/ammo from the shopping complex and building a fort. He couldn't figure out what calibre of bullets to use for the gun he found and had to read the store chart to figure it out.

This story was very memorable to me, and honestly always struck me as a very intriguing situation.

Anyway, the publishing date was probably pre-1980, because it looked old when I read it as a kid. The book itself was a soft-cover, maybe 200-300 pages.

The world seemed to be today's world, just without any other people being mentioned in the story. The store had stuff like canned peaches, and seemed to be in immaculate condition. The ending was that he killed the thing that was chasing him, which appeared to be his clone/himself. The book was notable for never using the main character's name, just calling him *The Man* and never used first person.

The cover had a picture of a scared-looking guy holding a revolver on it, while running.

Comment: sounds a bit like "I Am Legend" by Matheson

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am fairly sure that this is *Castaway*, a 1934 novella by [James Gould Cozzens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gould_Cozzens). The protagonist, Mr Lecky, is alone in a huge department store. It is never explained what has happened or how he came to be locked in the store.

> The guy was mortally afraid of someone or something that was chasing him

Lecky is nervous from the start, and becomes terrified when he discovers that there is another human roaming the department store -- and still more so when he realizes that the other man ‘could hardly be altogether sane’.

> spent a lot of time getting guns/ammo from the shopping complex and building a fort.

In the first chapter, Lecky equips himself with a shotgun and shells from the sporting goods department, and in the third chapter (entitled ‘The Fortification of the Lavatory’) he improvises a fort around a toilet.

> He couldn't figure out what caliber of bullets to use for the gun he found... and had to read the store chart to figure it out.

Several pages are devoted to Lecky's attempts to select and load a gun -- a frustrating business, since he knows nothing about firearms. Eventually,

> Mr. Lecky noticed on the far counter a heap of small booklets. He let his axe go and, taking one in his damp, unsteady hands, read INSTRUCTIONS FOR PURCHASERS on the cover.

With the aid of the booklet he manages to load a shotgun.

> Anyway, the publishing date was probably pre-1980

First published 1934; I had a hardback edition published in 1968, so it evidently remained in print for a while.

> The book itself was a soft-cover, maybe 200-300 pages.

My hardback was around 120 pages, so 200 might be about right for a paperback with smaller pages.

> The world seemed to be today's world, just without any other people being mentioned in the story.

The only characters in *Castaway* are Lecky and his unnamed adversary. The setting seems to be a normal, large 1930s department store with no anachronistic features.

> The store had stuff like canned peaches, and seemed to be in immaculate condition.

I'm not sure if canned peaches are specifically mentioned, but Lecky definitely lives on the non-perishables available in the food department, including cans and glass jars of fruit.

> The ending was that he killed the thing that was chasing him, which appeared to be his clone/himself.

The ending is rather surreal: Lecky succeeds in killing the other man (mostly referred to as ‘the idiot’ in the text) by shooting him with a shotgun and cutting his throat with a kitchen knife. At the end of the book, the dead idiot is somehow reanimated and crawls up the stairs to meet Lecky. It is not explicitly stated, but very strongly hinted, that Mr Lecky and the idiot are in some way the same person.

> The book was notable for never using the main character's name, just calling him The Man and never used first person.

Certainly the book never uses the first person, but the main character is referred to throughout by name as ‘Mr. Lecky’ (at least in my copy).

> The cover had a picture of a scared-looking guy holding a revolver on it, while running.

Here is the cover of a Bantam paperback edition.

[image: Cover of Bantam edition]

(Not very faithful to the text, since Lecky doesn't wield a revolver at any point as far as I can recall.)

Comment: My god you’ve found the exact version I read, that bantam paperback. Thank you so much, I read that book as a kid and never really thought I’d find it again. I’ll mark yours as he answer when I get back to my computer. Thank you so much mate!

Comment: @MeesterTeem You're welcome! It's a remarkable book and it stuck in my mind too (I think I read it about ten years ago). I enjoyed going through the plot again to put this answer together.